# discord.py updating a document in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that allows the user to update a reason on a warn to something else and I don't know how to update documents in mongodb

```
        check = list(warndb.warn_logs.find({"case_id": caseid}))
        for w in check:
            reason = w.get('reason')
            caseid = w.get('case_id')
            change = {{"reason": reason}, {"$set": {"reason": update}}}
            w.update(change, upsert=False)
            embed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title="Successfully updated reason", description=f"Updated reason for case {caseid}")
            embed.add_field(name="**Before:**", value=f"{reason}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="**Updated To:**", value=f"{update}", inline=False)
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return
```

Here's the main code that I have to update documents but I'm getting a couple of errors and I don't know how to update documents. please help

Answer (score 0):

So please provide full trace back but here is the code for update your mongo also check documention : [Mongo doc.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/)
In a cog it could look like this - arg would be the case id eg "!update_warn 123" then the arg would be 123 and also the case id

```
cluster = MongoClient('Your mongo link')
collection_name = cluster["Database Name"]["Collection Name"]

@commands.command()
async def update_warn(self,ctx,arg):
    check = collection_name.find_one({"case_id": arg})
    if check is None:
        await ctx.reply("No Case was found!")
    else:
        reason = check['reason']
        caseid = check['case_id']
        update = "Your Updated Reason"
        collection_name.update_one({'case_id':arg},{'$set':{'reason': update}})
        embed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title="Successfully updated reason", description=f"Updated reason for case {caseid}")
        embed.add_field(name="**Before:**", value=f"{reason}", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="**Updated To:**", value=f"{update}", inline=False)
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```